# checkbox value of diffrent form in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

how do I get the checked checkbox value in jquery. I am not able to get them by their form accordingly.
my code is:

```
<form action="" method="get" name="brandform" id="brandform">
        <?php

foreach ($ubrnds as $value) {
echo '<label>'.$value.'<input type="checkbox" value="'.$value.'" name="chkbrands[]" id="chkbrands[]" onclick="javascript:brand_search();" ></label>';       
}

?>
```

and

```
 var val = [];

    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
      val[i] = $(this).val();
       alert(val[i]);
    });

</form>
```

Comment: Wrapped in a DOM ready function?

Comment: *"I am not able to get them by their form accordingly."* - could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('input[name="chkbrands[]"]:checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('input[name="chkbrands[]"]', '#brandform');
```

it can be elaborate in this way

```
$('element', 'form');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the code once the DOM has loaded:

```
$(function(){

    var values = $('#brandform input[type="checkbox"]').map(function(i, e){
        return e.value;
    }).get();   
    console.log(values);
});
```